# Are there any good books on College Calculus 1?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

Hi guys I'm looking for some good books about college Calculus 1. Do you have any recommendations? Topics in order:

1-Sets

2-Inequalities

3-Function

4-Limits

5-Differentiation

6-Applications of Differentiation

Comment: Calculus by Michael Spivak https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/calculus-4

Comment: @SaifChoul: This question has been asked several times and lot of nice response. You might want to search for those.

Comment: "Are there any good books on College Calculus 1?" - I sure hope so! Or we would have all the students in the world using bad calculus books, and that just won't do

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [James Stewart's Calculus](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Calculus_Early_Transcendentals.html?id=hEF-BAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y) book. It's pretty good

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed **Best and Penner**'s book..

Answer (score 0):

I use [**Calculus 11e by Ron Larson**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1337275344). It's a pretty detailed book. Along with this book, you get free videos of solutions and free live chat with tutors.

See [Calcchat.com](http://Calcchat.com) and [Calcview.com](http://Calcview.com)